# Android. Problems when applying custom animation on multiple views

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have written my own shake animation to shake the `EditText`s. When I tap "SHAKE USER", the first `EditText` shakes. When I tap "SHAKE PASS", the two `EditText`s shake together, which should not happen. Screenshot is attached.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYVOC.png)

**Here is the animation file**
    `shake.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="2%"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="50" />
</set>
```

**Here is the Java code snippet**

```
Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);

findViewById(R.id.b1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            shakeView(etUser);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.b2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            shakeView(etPass);
        }
    });

private void shakeView(final View view) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.startAnimation(shake);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems that I have found the solution myself. I called `view.clearAnimation()` after the animation finishes, and everything is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I have found the solution myself. I called `view.clearAnimation()` after the animation finishes, and everything is working fine